# Connection refused on mysql with user granted on %

Tags: mysql, docker, permissions

I see other question like this here on S.O. but no one solved my problem.

I'm running MySQL using Docker, and on the first boot, I'm running some SQL queries to prepopolate the DB. One of those is the following:

```
CREATE USER 'user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'user';
Grant All Privileges ON *.* to 'user'@'%';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

However, when I try to connect to the DB from another container, I get:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: ...)
```

What am I doing wrong?

This happens both if I use the name of the container, and `127.0.0.1` as host

my docker-compose looks like this:

```
#MySQL Service
db:
  image: mysql
  container_name: db
  restart: unless-stopped
  tty: true
  ports:
    - "3307:3306"
    - "8001:3306"
  environment:
    ....
  volumes:
    - ./database/dbdata:/var/lib/mysql/:rw
    - ./config/mysql/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

the strangest part of all of this, is that if I connect to the DB with a MySQL client installed on my PC, the connection works fine...

`my.cnf` is the following:

```
[mysqld]
general_log = 1
general_log_file = /var/lib/mysql/general.log
secure-file-priv = NULL
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
```

Comment: @nbk added both my.cnf and the volumes I'm mounting

Comment: the only thing  i can think of, is that you haven't created the user with native_password, which must be done in mysql 8, but you gaven't posted which version you are using,

Comment: @nbk `mysql  Ver 8.0.25 for Linux on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)`

Comment: what is supposed to be `native_password`?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-user.html   when you install mysql you want to use legacy option. as i said you can try it

Comment: @nbk now I'm using `CREATE USER IF NOT EXISTS 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'user';`, no error is shown during creation and grant, but still the connection is refused... but I really don't understand why a MySQL client in my PC can connect to that container, but not other containers...

Comment: there i can only speclate that the package doesn't reach the container, maybe a check with wireshark, but  i am no docker fan

Comment: @nbk yes I can understand why... however now I've installed locally mysql and it's working (with the local version, not with the container)... let's see if someone will help ahah (tnk u so much btw)